# is HTTP FIN ACKed?

Tags: http

I write a remote system which connects over a cell network to my server. Now I want to ensure that data requested gets to my client completely. Thus I thought I could piggy back ride on http. But is http FIN ACKed and does it guarantee a complete transfer if code 200 is being received?
Always? 
Also, how does the server know that all the information provided was delivered completely to the client? Does this need to be done through an app level acknowledge?

Comment: HTTP doesn't have FIN or ACK - those are a lower layer. HTTP merely returns data down the TCP pipe. The client (through TCP) will know if the stream has been closed unexpectedly and it should only rely on a "guaranteed complete transfer" if the stream closes without error *and/or* (esp. in the case of pipelining) it retrieves all the HTTP data according to the response headers.